# How to rename a program installed via apt-get in Ubuntu

Tags: apt

I had installed a program using apt-get in Ubuntu. Anyway to rename the program other than uninstalling and reinstalling it?

Comment: At first glance I would say that not even uninstalling and reinstalling will do it. Why do you want to do it anyway?

Comment: Why would you ?

Comment: Yes, please be more precise as to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: If the answer below suits your needs please accept it. If not please comment.

Comment: If using aliases doesn't work for you, I would suggest making `symlink` in `PATH` This way original files wouldn't be changed and you could uninstall or upgrade that package in clean way with apt when needed. Please state use case or delete the question.

Comment: Use `update-alternatives`.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/271411). What are you actually trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

this is easy.

**What `apt` is**

first off, apt is a package management utility and uses the debian package management system. you use it to automate the process of managing installed packages (or applications) on your system. `apt` does not rename your packages for you since that's not really what it's used for.

you need the bash-builtin `alias` or the program `ln`. These are command-line utilities for `bash` (Borne Again SHell).

uninstalling any software is unnecessary unless you intend to no longer use that package. I highly advise against this as if you do not know what you are removing; *you risk ultimately making your system unusable*.

I usually suggest reading [The Linux Command Line](http://linuxcommand.org/tlcl.php) for beginners its free and helpful for understanding the basics of `bash`.

**Aliases**

you can use `help -m alias | less` to get more information on how to use it. typical usage usually looks like `alias ls='ls -lhAHF'` and the next time `ls` is executed, it is executed with the options as well.

example:

```
$ alias list='ls -lhAHF'
$ list
```

`list` outputs directory contents using the options given.

to see all available aliases, just execute `alias` on its own.

**note:** that all aliases are executed in the shell. you can make this permanent if you add it to your `~/.bashrc` file in your home directory.

**Links**

you can use `man ln` for find more information about creating links.

**Hard Links**

```
ln /path/to/file /new/path/and/new/filename
```

Creates a direct link to the file or directory specified.

**Symbolic Links**

This is probably the better method to use most often and is typically used to resolve constantly changing names to particular binary files.

For example, if you have a program named `progname.v1.2.12` it would be inconvenient to rely on this name for other programs. So you create a symbolic link to fix this issue, and you can name it whatever you'd like (usually).

```
ln -s progname.v1.2.12 progname
```

and then you can call `progname` since it is symbolically linked to the file. This is more akin to how MS Windows creates links.

**The Difference Between Hard and Symbolic Links?**

Basically, a hard link is as if it is actually the file or directory at hand.

The symbolic link is as if a shortcut or reference was created. This is usually formally referred to as a pointer.

**Conclusion**

I suggest using alias unless necessary.

Comment: Creating an alias is not the same as "renaming" but hopefully it will work for what the OP wants.

Comment: you make a good point.